# Automate testing all the themes in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would a way to automate plotting the same graph with all the themes available in the libraries `ggplot2` and `ggthemes`. Until now, the only way I've managed to do that is by (e.g):

```
qplot(data = mtcars, x = mtcars$mpg, y = mtcars$hp) + k
```

Where k could be set by `k <- theme_base()`.That being said, I could make a list of themes and `k` being the variable that iterates over this list.

Then, what is an affordable way of creating this lits, besides adding theme by theme as an element of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
# dput(ls(pattern = "theme",package:ggplot2))
defaults <- c("theme_bw", "theme_classic", "theme_dark", 
              "theme_grey", "theme_light", "theme_linedraw", 
              "theme_minimal", "theme_void")
library(ggthemes)
# dput(ls(pattern = "theme",package:ggthemes))
addons <- c("theme_base", "theme_calc", "theme_economist", 
            "theme_economist_white", "theme_excel", "theme_few", "theme_fivethirtyeight", 
            "theme_foundation", "theme_gdocs", "theme_hc", "theme_igray", 
            "theme_map", "theme_pander", "theme_par", "theme_solarized", 
            "theme_solarized_2", "theme_solid", "theme_stata", "theme_tufte", 
            "theme_wsj")

p <- ggplot(mtcars) + facet_wrap(~vs) +
  stat_qq(aes(sample = mpg, colour = factor(cyl)), geom="line")

pl1 <- lapply(defaults, function(th) p + get(th)() + ggtitle(th))
pl2 <- lapply(addons, function(th) p + get(th)() + ggtitle(th))

library(gridExtra)
library(Cairo)
CairoPDF("all_themes.pdf", width=8, height=32)
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(grobs=pl1, top = "Original themes", ncol=2),
             arrangeGrob(grobs=pl2[-c(17:18)], top = "Third-party themes", ncol=2), heights=c(0.4, 1))
dev.off()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir7zr.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This looks up all the objects that begin with the string "them" in the ggplot2 environment:

```
 thems <- ls(patt="^them", envir=environment(ggplot) )
 thems
 #   -----
 [1] "theme"          "theme_bw"       "theme_classic"  "theme_dark"     "theme_env"      "theme_get"     
 [7] "theme_gray"     "theme_grey"     "theme_light"    "theme_linedraw" "theme_minimal"  "theme_replace" 
[13] "theme_set"      "theme_update"   "theme_void"
```

Comment: I wrote done the answer but then erased it. It annoys the heck out of me to find that people are removing votes as some sort of inducement to answer add on questions.

Comment: At least this time it was not a inducement for you. I taught that if it was marked as answered anyone else besides you would enter in the post. I was just increasing the chance of someone else entering in the post. However, you are right, it was not a gentle move

Comment: You are NOT supposed to use comments to change the question. You are welcome to change the checkmark if someone offers a better solution. You are also allowed to uncheck answers but you should be prepared for a reaction.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstandings, but apart from unchecking the answer I  don't see were I've infringe any kind of rule/ethic. The comment did not change the question what so ever. You gave me an awesome answer, but it was not complete as your idea didn't work for the `ggtheme` package (or at least it is not obvious for me). I think you are going only to get more angry as I'm still a ignorant in this type of stuff and you are a erudite

Comment: You got an error because "ggthemes" is not an object name in the `ggthemes` namespace, so `environment(ggthemes)` errors out, whereas `ggplot` is an object in the `ggplot2` namespace. What I wrote and erased  showed the use of a random ggpthemes function as the "handle" to get the proper environment